# javascript Array in IE11 not processing the values correctly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a problem with a Javascript array in IE11 mainly in the for loop.

Here is the code:

```
    function onResponseReceived(responseArray) {
      found = true;
      var i;

      for(i in responseArray) {
        var item = responseArray[i];
        if (item.field_number == '5') {
            item.value = intlToUsDate(item.value);
            console.log(item.value);
        }

        var inputSelector = '[name="input_' + item.field_number + '"]';
        var dom_elms = document.querySelectorAll(inputSelector);

        for (var e in dom_elms) {
            var dom_elm = dom_elms[e];
            if (dom_elm.type == 'radio' || dom_elm.type == 'checkbox') {
                if (dom_elm.value == item.value && !dom_elm.checked) {
                    dom_elm.click();
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                dom_elm.value = item.value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output in IE11 using the console.log:

```
"
i
d
"
:

"
1
8
4
1
"
,
```

Here is an the output for the same Javascript using Chrome:

```
field_number
:
"5"
form_id
:
"10"
id
:
"1839"
is_synced
:
"1"
lead_id
:
"2967"
value
:
"05/08/2018"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Basically it process the information correctly.

In IE11, how can I have the array be an object like in Chrome,FF or Edge?

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: There is no way we can help you unless you post a complete, executable example. We need to be able to replicate your issue.

Comment: It is extremely likely that `for (var e in dom_elms)` is used in error. The NodeList has properties that are not elements. So `dom_elm.type` and `dom_elm.value` will both choke on the `length` property of the NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns not an array but a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), and its documentation says:

> Don't be tempted to use **for...in** or **for each...in** to enumerate the
>   items in the list, since that will also enumerate the length and item
>   properties of the NodeList and cause errors if your script assumes it
>   only has to deal with element objects.

Therefore instead of below code

```
for (var e in dom_elms) {
  var dom_elm = dom_elms[e];
  :
}
```

you should use for IE:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(dom_elms, function(dom_elm) {
  :       
});
```

Comment: Right, but that doesn't explain the behavior the OP suggests - works in all browsers except IE11. Would really like the OP to explain that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn explanation added

Comment: So basically I should Array.prototype.forEach.call(responseArray, function(response_array

Comment: @KevinDavis all you need to do is to replace those two lines in DOM `for` loop with one line provided in answer

Comment: I'm still getting the issue. The problem lies within the code:var item = responseArray[i];

Comment: @KevinDavis It is not clear what is the type of responseArray, if it is not array then try `alert(typeof responseArray)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to add the following code:

```
    var responseArray = JSON.parse(responseArray);
```